# Is it possible to delay iPhone from detecting motion until a view fades from the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a crystal ball (single view) application that I need a fix for. There is a UILabel, which shows brief instructions, that appears upon the first launch of the application. I would like to disable the motion detection until the user taps the screen to dismiss the instructions. As of now, while the instructions are displayed, the user can shake the device, which displays the prediction. Is there a way to disable the motionBegan method until the user dismisses the instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `BOOL` instance variable and use it as a flag to indicate if the instructional view has been dismissed yet. Then, add a check inside your `motionBegan` method to see if it should do anything or not. Something like this:

```
//.h
BOOL instructionsDoneShowing;

//.m

//Wherever your instructions screen is dismissed
instructionsDoneShowing = TRUE;

//Inside your motionBegan method
if (instructionsDoneShowing) {

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After initiation of your view, say

```
[yourView resignFirstResponder];
```

When user dismisses the instructions say -

```
[yourView becomeFirstResponder];
```